# I'm having trouble scraping multiple URL's

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm having trouble scraping multiple URLs. Essentially I'm able to run this for only one genre, but the second I include other links it stops working.

The goal is to get the data and place it into a csv file with the movie title, url, and genre. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = ['https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1365', 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7424']

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"nm-content-horizontal-row-item"})


# name the output file to write to local disk
out_filename = "netflixaction2.csv"
# header of csv file to be written
headers = "Movie_Name, Movie_ID \n"

# opens file, and writes headers
f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)



for container in containers:
    
    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"nm-collections-title nm-collections-link"})
    title_container = title_container[0].text

    movieid = container.findAll("a",{"class":"nm-collections-title nm-collections-link"})
    movieid = movieid[0].attrs['href']

    print("Movie Name: " + title_container, "\n")
    print("Movie ID: " , movieid, "\n")

    f.write(title_container + ", " + movieid + "\n")
f.close()  # Close the file
```

Comment: Since you are using open(out_filename, "w") which overrides what you write in your file. Can you try change to "a" instead of "w" and see if that solves? If it does then I will post as a solution :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't.

I'm met with this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tghan\autoscrape3.py", line 6, in <module>
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
  File "C:\Users\tghan\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\tghan\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 516, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
[Finished in 0.3s]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is that you trying to do a GET requests on a list.

```
my_url = ['https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1365', 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7424']

uClient = uReq(my_url)
```

what I suggest to do here is to loop through each link etc:

```
my_url = ['https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1365', 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7424']

for link in my_url:
    uClient = uReq(link)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    ....
```

and to mention, if you are just applying the code for the loop, it will override your f.write function. What you need to do is something like:

New edit:

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# All given URLS
my_url = ['https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1365', 'https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7424']

# Create and open CSV file
with open("netflixaction2.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    # Headers for CSV
    headers_for_csv = ['Movie Name', 'Movie Link']

    # Small function for csv DictWriter
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers_for_csv)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    # We need to loop through each URL from the list
    for link in my_url:

        # Do a simple GET requests with the URL
        response = requests.get(link)

        page_soup = soup(response.text, "html.parser")

        # Find all nm-content-horizontal-row-item
        containers = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class": "nm-content-horizontal-row-item"})

        # Loop through each found "li"
        for container in containers:
            movie_name = container.text.strip()
            movie_link = container.find("a")['href']

            print(f"Movie Name: {movie_name} | Movie link: {movie_link}")

            # Write to CSV
            csv_writer.writerow({
                'Movie Name': movie_name,
                'Movie Link': movie_link,
            })

# Close the file
csv_file.close()
```

That should be your solution :) Feel free to comment if i'm missing something!

Comment: Thanks for this! However, the problem that results from this is that it only get data from the very first url in my_url and ignores any subsequent urls.

Comment: Hi, it is abit hard for me to know the expected result since you have not provided it. But I think your problem might relate to what you are trying to scrape. If you could provide more info etc what you trying to scrape and expected result that would be helpful for all us who trying to help :)

Comment: Of course, currently with a single link the result is that I'd have content from netflix.com/genre/browse/1365 (the action genre) scrapped and placed into and csv file with the headers "Movie Name" and "Movie ID" ID in this case would be the url. 

What I'm looking to do is that same thing however instead of having to change the (1365) and run separately I'd look to run each url at once by including all of them from the beginning i.e.

www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1365
www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7424
etc

Comment: @AnthonyGhanime I have now updated with a new code and more simple than what you had before, please feel free if there is something you miss understand. I quite not sure still what you are looking after. Specially that you said: `What I'm looking to do is that same thing however instead of having to change the (1365) and run separately` - There is more work to do where you need to add threading and also lock the CSV so you dont override each other etc etc.. Please don't forget to put it as the answer if it is something you were looking for :)